# Why use LUV color space to present objects in object detection?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

In this paper,[Fast feature pyramids for object detection](http://vision.ucsd.edu/sites/default/files/DollarPAMI14pyramids_0.pdf),they use LUV color space to present pedestrians.After I searched more papers, i found many of papers used LUV color space.

My questions:
1)what's the advantages of LUV color space over RGB in object detection?
2)what's the characteristic of LUV color space?

Thanks.

Comment: It's very well explained in wikipedia, you know.

Comment: Right. I feel confused after looking through WIKI, could you tell me are there any advantages to use LUV color features instead of RGB in object detection?

Answer (score 7):

A non-technical answer:

There are two reasons we might use non-RGB colorspaces, including LUV, in computer vision. The first reason is that differences in RGB space do not correspond well to perceived differences in color. That is, two colors can be close in RGB space but appear very different to humans and vice versa. The second reason (and I would say the more important one for object detection) is that spaces like LUV decouple the "color" (chromaticity, the UV part) and "lightness" (luminance, the L part) of color. Thus in object detection, it is common to match objects just based on the UV part, which gives invariance to changes in lighting condition.